# splice array javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo un problema y no se como poder solucionarlo...
Quiero borrar un string de un array si no es checked, hasta ahi funciona bien pero siempre me borra el primer elemento del array, quiero borrar el que no esta chequeado.
No se como poder plantear la función si alguien me puede aconsejar!
GRACIAS

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  if ($('#gift')[0] != null) {
    var message = [];
    $('#input_gift')[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('SHIPPING.TPL');
      if ($('#input_gift')[0].checked === true) {
        $('#cart-summary-product-list')[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
          for (let index = 0; index < $('.label_input input').length; index++) {
            $('.label_input input')[index].addEventListener('click', () => {
              if ($('.label_input input')[index].checked === true) {
                console.log('if ' + uniqueMessage);
                message.push($('.label_input input')[index].name);
              } else {
                console.log('else '+  uniqueMessage);
                message.splice($('.label_input input')[index].name,1);
              }
            })
          }

          function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
            return self.indexOf(value) === index;
          }
          var uniqueMessage = message.filter(onlyUnique);
          console.log('envio ->' + uniqueMessage);
          $('#gift_message')[0].innerText = uniqueMessage;
        })
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: he intentado con  message.splice($('.label_input input')[index].name,index); I nada. Y si no pongo nada los borra todos. Solo quiero borrar el que no este chequeado en el caso de que haya mas de dos y uno este y el otro no. Si pongo 1 siempre borra el primero de la lista

Comment: Prueba con un message.filter(msg => msg !== unCheckedValue). Intenta limpiar el código un poco y declarar const. Es complicado de leer y te ayudará a depurar errores como el que tienes.

Comment: Puedes añadir el HTML? me parece que parte del problema es que tienes varios elementos con el mismo ID

Answer (score 0):

Estás pasando como primer argumento el valor que corresponde al atributo `name`. Lo que tienes que pasar es la posición:

```
message.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: si, era eso, aunque lo había probado... no se porque ese día no iba jejej Gracias !

Comment: Otra cosa, la primera vez no incluye ninguno. Mete un string vacío... tengo que clicar dos veces para que empice y aun asi  no va del todo bien.. si me puedes ayudar a depurarlo